# Is there an upper limit on lineWidth for any arbitrary shaped cgPath beyond which path strokes behave abnormally?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I get my path from CTFontCreatePathForGlyph for english characters. The path is made up of dozens of subpaths joining at all kinds of angles.
I use pathJoin = .round and path.cap = round.

If I go on increasing the lineWidth of the path after a limit I start gearing holes in the stroke where there should be none.[image: these have both lineWIdth ~ 60 and fontSize ~ 40]